# Modulus of Continuity of a $x^{\alpha}$

Tags: functional-analysis

How do I show that modulus of continuity, $\omega(f,\delta)$ where $f(x):=x^{\alpha}$, is $\leq c\delta^{\alpha}$ where c is some constant independent of $\delta$. ($0 <\alpha < 1$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since domain of $f$ is positive integers we have
$$
\omega(f,\delta)
=\sup_{|x-y|\leq 2\delta,\;\;x,y\in D(f)}|f(x)-f(y)|
=\sup_{|x-y|\leq 2\delta,\;\;x,y\geq 0}|f(x)-f(y)|
$$
Since $f$ is strictly increasing, then
$$
\begin{align}
\omega(f,\delta)
&=\sup_{|x-y|\leq 2\delta,\;\;x,y\geq 0}|f(x)-f(y)|\\
&=\sup_{|x-y|= 2\delta,\;\;x,y\geq 0}|f(x)-f(y)|\\
&=\sup_{x\geq 0}|f(x+2\delta)-f(x)|\\
&=\sup_{x\geq 0}(f(x+2\delta)-f(x))\\
\end{align}
$$
Using the fact that $\alpha-1<0$ it is routine task to check that $f(x+2\delta)-f(x)$ is strictly decreasing on $[0,+\infty)$. Hence
$$
\omega(f,\delta)
=\sup_{x\geq 0}(f(x+2\delta)-f(x))
=f(0+2\delta)-f(0)=(2\delta)^{\alpha}
$$

Comment: According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulus_of_continuity $\omega$ depent only on the argument $t$.

Comment: For a fixed f...