# Modulus of continuity of $(1-x)^{a}$

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Fixed $a>0$, define $f(x):=(1-x)^{a}$ for each $x\in [0,1]$. Recalling that the modulus of continuity of $f$ of order $\varepsilon>0$ is given by

$\omega(f;\varepsilon):=\sup\{|f(x)-f(y)|: |x-y|\leq \varepsilon\}$,

How can we find  an upper bound for $\omega(f;\varepsilon)$? I have seen a proof in the post

[Modulus of Continuity of a $x^{\alpha}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/511528/modulus-of-continuity-of-a-x-alpha)

for the funcion $x^{\alpha}$, but I do not see clear the proof. Can you help me, please?

Very thanks in advance for your comments.

Comment: $|x-y|=|(1-x)-(1-y)|$: it is the same question.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand the equality and it relation with the post.